# Store intent for one activity but start a different activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I am new to android and I have a problem. I want to store intent for an activity but start a different activity. I have a backgroundworker activity that has to store intent for postAnnotationActivity, but has to start InstructionsActivity. If I use `intentID.getStringExtra` in PostAnnotationActivity then the output = `null`. Can somebody help?

Part of code from Backgroundworker:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, InstructionsActivity.class);
        Intent intentID = new Intent(context, PostAnnotationsActivity.class);
        intentID.putExtra(ID, id);
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

part of PostAnnotationActivity:

```
    Intent intentID = getIntent();
    String getID = intentID.getStringExtra(BackgroundWorker.ID);
```

From InstructionsActivity I'll go to StartActivty using `startActivity(new Intent(this, ShowPaintingActivity.class)`and then to PostAnnotationActivity using `startActivity(new Intent(this, PostAnnotationsActivity.class));`

Comment: With the code you posted you will start InstructionsActivity. Please show how you start PostAnnotationActivity.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: So basically you want to pass the intent extra (= the value of "id") to PostAnnotationsActivity? Is there any reason why you don't want to use SharedPreferences?

Comment: Because I wasn't familiar with SharedPreferences ;). I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing your Intent instead as a string and use shared preferences to store/retrieve your Intent. Like so.

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    editor.putString("StoredIntent", "String you want to store here");
    editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code as following:

In Backgroundworker:

```
 Intent intentID = new Intent(context, InstructionsActivity.class);
 intentID.putExtra("ID", id);
 context.startActivity(intentID);
```

In InstructionsActivity:

```
 Intent intentID = getIntent();
 String getID = intentID.getStringExtra("ID");

 Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowPaintingActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("ID", getID);
 context.startActivity(intent);
```

In ShowPaintingActivity:

```
 Intent intentID = getIntent();
 String getID = intentID.getStringExtra("ID");

 Intent intent = new Intent(context, PostAnnotationActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("ID", getID);
 context.startActivity(intent);
```

In PostAnnotationActivity:

```
Intent intentID = getIntent();
String getID = intentID.getStringExtra("ID");
```

And another better solution is, as user1375469 suggested, you can save value to preferences in Backgroundworker and then retrieve it from PostAnnotation Activity.

Comment: Bu then i go directly from Backgroundworker to PostAnnotationsActivity? I want to go to my InstuctionsActivity but already store some data from BackgroundWorker for PostAnnotationActivity

Comment: Yes I think this will solve my problem, but I'll take a look into ShardePreferences. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting the output null because you are not starting the Activity i.e.

```
 context.startActivity(intentID);
```

while you are passing the data into it..
and you want to go to my InstuctionsActivity but already store some data from BackgroundWorker for PostAnnotationActivity....
So, you have to use SharedPreference for this purpose....